# What is the most used and flexible SMTP Client library in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, smtp

I'm looking to crowd-source this, as I'm having bit of difficulty finding an "industry standard" library for SMTP in C/C++.

I'm looking for the ability to send emails with different MIME formats and attachments.  I'd rather not re-invent the wheel by writing a thinly veiled library.  But I'd also like to be able to include it in my software without odd licensing issues.

I've read over this related article: [What RFCs need to be considered in developing an SMTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908967/what-rfcs-need-to-be-considered-in-developing-an-smtp-client), regarding the RFCs which are relevant, and I'm looking over the RFCs too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My personal favourite is [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/), for C++ only, but the highly reputed [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) also has SMTP support (as well as many other features).

VMime has a [dual license](http://www.vmime.org/pages/Licensing); I think curl has a sort of MIT-style license.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm looking into these.  I didn't know that libcURL had SMTP support either, that's something worth investigating.

Comment: I am having problems compiling VMime on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

[libquickmail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/) has all the features you need.
It supports things like multiple alternative bodies and attachments.