# non blocking sendmail in C

Tags: sendmail, nonblocking

I am trying to send an email from my C program on linux (centos 64bit).  The following (simplified) code works a treat:

```
asprintf(&cmd,"/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t -f me@blah.com somebody@blah.com");
asprintf(&bdy,"From: me@blah.com\nTo: somebody@blah.com\nSubject: blah blah\n\nThis is the message body\n");

FILE *out = popen(cmd,"w");
fprintf(out,"%s",bdy);
pclose(out);
```

The problem is it blocks and takes up to a second or 2 before returning.  How to send an email without blocking?

More info:  The problem is that popen blocks and waits to complete before returning.  So I'm probably looking for another way to use sendmail.  I really don't want to use additional libraries with all that bloat.  I would prefer not to fork if at all possible. (popen already forks, but then waits to complete before returning to the caller)  Is there a popen equivalent that doesnt block?

Comment: I guess the problem is not really from `popen`, bur rather that the same invocation directly in a shell will also take some time? "Slow" sendmail may indicate problems with the DNS configuration on the local machine.

Comment: Actually it has everything to do with popen which by design, will block and wait until the task is completed.  At the moment, the best solution I have thought of so far is to write the emails to files and have a bash script send them.  But this is messy and I would much rather do it all within C.

Comment: Still, submitting an email to your MTA should not take so long, as generally the mail is just spooled (unless you changed your setup).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to send from a different thread (which could be as simple as using [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)), which lets your program continue executing while sending the mail

Comment: I won't call `fork` a syscall related to multi-threading. It is related to multi-processing.

Comment: My understanding is that popen forks anyway. But it blocks until it finishes so as to provide output to the parent. I don't want this information.  I just want to continue

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Multi-processing is also multi-threading. If you have N non-zombie processes, you have at least N threads.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use some SMTP client library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8995476/841108).

You might set up your machine as an SMTP [smart host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host).

You could also directly use low-level process related syscalls like [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), etc.... Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to learn more.

You could dare use multi-threading. Learn more about [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Comment: I don't want to use a client library or a smart host.  I want to know if there is any way to send an email without blocking and without using other libraries.

Comment: The SMTP protocol may involve delays, which you call (incorrectly) "blocking".

Comment: The SMTP mail sending takes as long as it takes, but I don't want my C program to wait around for it to finish.  I want it to issue the call to send, and then carry on.  I don't actually care how long it takes to send the email.  Are you saying there is no blocking going on and the cpu is flat out for a whole second to send a single email?