# SMTP Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: You must authenticate first (#5.5.1)

Tags: c#, smtp, email

I am trying to send email to some of my colleagues using a program. This program is working fine at my own desktop but is giving an error

Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: You must authenticate first (#5.5.1)

on one of our servers in remote location. Can someone point out the error I have tried to change the position of the line of authentication. And I am not able to deduce much from the error. The same username and password are being used at both locations.

```
public static Boolean sendemail(String strFrom, string strTo, string strCC, string strBCC, string strReplyTO, string strSubject, string strBody, string strAttachmentPath, bool IsBodyHTML)
    {
        //Array arrToArray;
        //char[] splitter = { ';' };
        //arrToArray = strTo.Split(splitter);
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        bool flag = isEmailsString(strFrom);
        if (flag)
        {
            mm.From = new MailAddress(strFrom);
        }
        flag = isEmailsString(strTo);
        if (flag)
        {
            mm.To.Add(strTo);
        }
        flag = isEmailsString(strCC);
        if (flag)
        {
            mm.CC.Add(strCC);
        }
        flag = isEmailsString(strBCC);
        if (flag)
        {
            mm.Bcc.Add(strBCC);
        }

        flag = Regex.IsMatch(strReplyTO.Trim(), @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
        if (strReplyTO != null)
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                mm.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(strReplyTO);
            }
        }

        if (strSubject != null)
        {
            mm.Subject = strSubject;
        }
        mm.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHTML;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAttachmentPath))
        {
            Array attachmentArray;
            char[] attachSplitter = { ',' };
            attachmentArray = strAttachmentPath.Split(attachSplitter);
            foreach (string s in attachmentArray)
            {
                string st = s.Trim();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(st))
                {
                    Attachment attach = new Attachment(st);
                    // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
                    mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
                    //strBodyFinal.Append(Environment.NewLine+"Go to the following link for more information"+Environment.NewLine);
                    //strBodyFinal.Append(st);
                }
            }
        }
        if (strBody != null)
        {
            mm.Body = strBody;
        }
        //foreach (string s in arrToArray)
        // {
        //     mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));
        // }
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "my user name";
            NetworkCred.Password = "my password";
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Host = "my company mail site";//host of your mail account
            //smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Port = 2525;//port no of your mail account 
            smtp.Timeout = 500000;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mm.Dispose();
            smtp = null;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use an SMTP client library.

Comment: can you suggest a good one.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8995476/841108

Comment: can you tell how I can use these with c#

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.answersthatwork.com/Download_Area/ATW_Library/Networking/Network__3-SMTP_Server_Status_Codes_and_SMTP_Error_Codes.pdf): `SMTP Error 551 : If neither the sending mail address nor
the recipient’s address are locally hosted by the server,
then the ISP’s servers may refuse to relay the message
on.` (page 21)

Comment: do you know of a workaround?

Comment: @puneet Did you even read the link? On page 21, as I said above: `To correct the problem you have to call your ISP and ask them to enter your domain name as an allowed sender.`

Comment: So many views but no upvote. This error seems to be very common.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched a lot about the issue and finding different interpretations for the error message like: **MAIL command issued after BDAT command** so it says **Bad sequence of commands**. But actually the problem was sorted when I changed my code above to

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // <<<you need THIS
System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "my user name";
NetworkCred.Password = "my password";
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Host = "my company mail site";//host of your mail account
smtp.Port = 2525;//port no of your mail account 
smtp.Timeout = 500000;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

Notice that `UseDefaultCredentials` is set to `false` before the `Credentials` are assigned new credentials. This change of sequence of setting default to `false` magically worked for me.

Comment: I had the same error I didn't have access to the source code so I solved it by editing the web.config setting `<network defaultCredentials="false" host="mymailserver.com" password="pw" userName="user@mymailserver.com" />` (the `defaultCredentials` setting was originally set to "true").

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record Network Solution SMTP seems to NEED the username in lowercase.
**Why? Just cuz, that's why.**

Hope it helps.. took me a very long time to figure it out..

Pat NH USA

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the mail from a different server (may be from your `localhost`) then this error comes, so if you want to test your `smtp mail` code you need to **upload your code to your remote server and test** (`plesk server` in my case) then it will work.

Comment: Why do you think that an SMTP connection is not possible from a local server?

Comment: I am not telling its not possible from local server, to make `smtp.Send(message)` work from local server we need to change the server mail configuration(the configuration of the server whose email id is used to send the mail) to allow user to send the mail from other servers

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @puneet that mentions `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false` got us on the right track.

But our case was slightly different. We also got error `Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: You must authenticate first (#5.5.1)` but it only happened on password resets using the Password Recovery web part built in to ASP.NET Membership.

The Password Recovery web part relies on a `web.config` section called `<mailSettings>` so we changed `defaultCredentials="true"` to `defaultCredentials="false"` in `web.config`

```
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="donotreply@someone.net">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="mail.someone.net" userName="notifier@someone.net" password="password" port="587" />
</smtp>
```

And this fixed the error with Password Reset. Basically this is the same fix as @puneet but in a different location.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smtp"]);                

//code by cv 8july2014
mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // <<<you need THIS
System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "username";
NetworkCred.Password = "Pasword";
mailClient.Credentials = NetworkCred;
//   mailClient.Host = "my company mail site";//host of your mail account
mailClient.Port = 2525;

// mailMsg = null;
//SmtpMail.SmtpServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smtp"];

while (counter < 3)
{
    try
    {
        mailClient.Send(mailMsg);        
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        counter = 3;
        mailMsg = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter == 2)
        {
            throw ex;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```